# Cakephp Email Intermittent Deliverability Trouble

Tags: php, email, cakephp

Using Cakephp 2.4.7.

We use the CakeEmail component to create email. 
We put up our own Postfix/Dovecot email server and spent the last 3 months chasing our tails. We have fought through every stinkin' possible problem I ever imagined possible with email, even though I know that all the smart people say don't even attempt self hosting email, I've done successfully 3 times before, so I really didn't think it would be a big deal to do it once more.

The issue is 15% of the email we send out, is either not delivered, or delivered as spam, with no consistency as to which domains fail.

We have fussed with SPF/DKIM/DMARC. We have submitted and validated domain ownership with the major domains. We validated that our ip address is not on any blacklists. I have hired three different email "experts" that have each spent weeks trying to fix this.

Well, I finally threw in the towel and signed up to have Rackspace handle email. 
And this morning I find out that I'm still having the same problem. 7 out of 30 emails, to different domains, were either not delivered, or delivered to spam.

I called Rackspace. They said it's not their problem. They say that the spam score on my outbound email is 0. (we're not talking about 1000s of newsletters here. We're talking about 30 individual emails to single addresses.)

The only thing I can think of at this point, is that there is something about the way that Cakephp is constructing email that is causing some servers to choke.

Is anyone aware of any known issues? Has anyone experienced anything like this? With Cake or otherwise? I'm lost. I don't know what to do now.

Was thinking I would try Google Apps and see if that makes a difference. But I kind of think it has something to do with how the email is constructed.

I'm sure I'm going to get hate comments over this question being too vague or whatever, but I've run out of ideas for where to even begin trying to solve this. So please.... if you don't feel like you can offer a constructive comment or helpful word of encouragement... please find some other poor soul to flame on. I'm feeling bad enough without somebody telling me I'm stupid.

ANY thoughts will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I recently had some weird issues with sending HTML mail using CakePHP; at seemingly random spots characters were missing or there was an extra space. Turned out that the lines in the HTML part of the email were too long and the mail server would force a line break there.

I'm not sure though if that is enough to cause a mail reject or spam-flag (though corrupt HTML might get rejected).

To prevent this issue HTML is sometimes base64-encoded in the mail to circumvent the line length; the alternative is to make sure all HTML output contains enough linebreaks.

Of course, what would be interesting is some entries from your maillog that tell you why mail wasn't delivered.